# Why does this new JObject strangely change my string when adding to it?

Tags: powershell, json.net

I have a PowerShell script, whose objective is to convert an incoming JSON object into a different sort of JSON object. (The "why" falls outside of the scope of this question.) The script (so far) is below (URL is obfuscated and will not work):

```
function Map-TempStudents {
    param($uffStudent)  # JObject containing UFF-formatted student

    [String]$districtCode = $uffStudent.Item("DistrictCode").ToString()
    Write-Host "districtCode = " $districtCode

    $tempStudent = New-Object -TypeName Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject
    $tempStudent.Add("DistrictNum", $uffStudent.Item("DistrictCode").ToString())

    Write-Host "tempStudent(DistrictNum) = " $tempStudent.Item("DistrictNum").ToString()
}

$currentPath = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$jsonNetPath = $currentPath + '\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
Add-Type -Path $jsonNetPath

$wc = New-Object system.Net.WebClient;
$studentPersonal = $wc.downloadString("http://test.foo.org/StudentPersonal")
$json = [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject]::Parse($studentPersonal)

$studentPersonal | Out-File "test.txt"  # DEBUG

$studentBases = $json.Item("Data").Item("AssignTeacher")
Map-TempStudents -uffStudent $studentBases[0]
```

Running this script gives the following output:

```
districtCode =  0745
tempStudent(DistrictNum) =  485
```

To be clear, "0745" is the correct value, and "485" is the unexpected value.

I would expect tempStudent(DistrictNum) to be "0745" as well.

Why would this value change like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue with the following script (assuming Newtonsoft.Json.dll is already loaded into PowerShell):

```
$jo = New-Object -TypeName Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject
$jo.Add("foo", "0745")
Write-Host $jo.Item("foo").ToString()
```

The `Add` method on `JObject` accepts an `object` as its second argument.  If you pass a numeric string with a leading zero (and all the digits are less than 8), it is interpreted as an octal number.  Hence "0745" gets converted into "485".  This must be a PowerShell thing, because the equivalent code in C# works correctly:

```
JObject jo = new JObject();
jo.Add("foo", "0745");
Console.WriteLine(jo["foo"].ToString());
```

To prevent the unwanted conversion in PowerShell, wrap your string in a `JValue` before passing it to `JObject.Add()`, e.g.:

```
$jval = New-Object -TypeName Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue -ArgumentList "0745"
$jo.Add("foo", $jval)
```

Here is the corrected `Map-TempStudents` function:

```
function Map-TempStudents {
    param($uffStudent)  # JObject containing UFF-formatted student

    $districtCode = New-Object -TypeName Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JValue -ArgumentList $uffStudent.Item("DistrictCode").ToString()
    Write-Host "districtCode = " $districtCode.ToString()

    $tempStudent = New-Object -TypeName Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject
    $tempStudent.Add("DistrictNum", $districtCode)

    Write-Host "tempStudent(DistrictNum) = " $tempStudent.Item("DistrictNum").ToString()
}
```

Comment: Thank you - even if not the most elegant solution, it does get the job done!